CSS backdrop-filter + backface-visibility not working on iOS
I have created a flipcard with text content on the front and the back.
I have applied a blur to the card but on iOS is very glitchy.
.blur {
  backdrop-filter: blur(9px);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(9px);
}

I have searched the web and found similar issues but nobody was using blur with
backface-visibility: hidden

I searched and found similar issues with backdrop-filter but the solutions for these problems were to apply -webkit-backdrop-filter which i have already applied and not working in my case.
The text is not clear all the time and while turning the card it gets blurried.

Code Snippet
(also on CodePen)


var card = document.querySelector(".card");
card.addEventListener("click", function () {
  card.classList.toggle("flipped");
});
body {
  margin: 0;
  /*   background-color: green; */
  background-image: url("https://i.natgeofe.com/n/c9107b46-78b1-4394-988d-53927646c72b/1095_4x3.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
}

.container {
  width: 80vw;
  height: 300px;
  perspective: 600px;
  margin: auto;
}

.card {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-origin: center right;
  transition: transform 1s;
}

.card.flipped {
  transform: translateX(-100%) rotateY(-180deg);
}

.card__face {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  background: rgb(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
  color: #03446a;
  font-size: 2rem;
}

.card__face--front {
}

.card__face--back {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.blur {
  backdrop-filter: blur(9px);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(9px);
}
<div class="container">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card__face card__face--front blur">
      Front
    </div>
    <div class="card__face card__face--back blur">
      Back
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



